# Angular: wrapper component to pass inner directives/components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-template

I have 3 components:

(1) **AppComponent**: This is just a regular *AppComponent*, nothing special. In *app.component.html* I use my *MyComponent*:

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

(2) **MyComponent**: This is just a wrapper component that contains *TheirComponent* like this (*my.component.html*):

```
<their-component></their-component>
```

(3) **TheirComponent**: This is a third-party component (from an NPM package). It can contain directives and other components from the third-party components. For example:

```
<their-component>
    <their-header>Title</their-header>
    <their-footer>Title</their-footer>
</their-component>
```

---

My goal is to put all of these additional, inner directives and components (`their-header` and `their-footer` in this example) in *app.component.html*, and pass it through *MyComponent* to *TheirComponent*. So my *app.component.html* should look like this:

```
<my-component>
    <their-header>Title</their-header>
    <their-footer>Title</their-footer>
</my-component>
```

---

I tried to use `ng-content` for this. It works with simple HTML elements, I know, but not with these third-party directives. This is what I tried (*my.component.html*):

```
<their-component>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</their-component>
```

It doesn't work, and there are no errors. Maybe this is a content projection problem, I'm not sure, how this is called. Any solution for this? Thanks.

---

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/SgM4sbYQrZXDcrKuon2d?p=preview

Comment: Why don't you just import the Component? Why do you need to pass it to the parent that way?

Comment: @Aer0 I have to wrap the third-party component, because I have to write some methods and parameters that are very commonly used in my application with this component. But the inner directives/components are unique for each use case, so I can't put them in my.component.html.

Comment: Did you try wrapping them in an `<ng-container>`?

Comment: Yes, a long time ago, but it had some issues, and it is not dynamic enough. They have too many components and directives. Or should I put all of the directives in a big `ng-template` (in *app.component.html*), that I can use in an `ng-template` (in *my.component.html*)?

Comment: @Aer0 I tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: I've kind of trouble understanding your current promel. Could you eventually set up a small demo so we can follow up all of your thoughts? E.g. here https://codesandbox.io/s/angular

Comment: @Aer0 Codesandbox didn't worked, but check this one out: https://plnkr.co/edit/SgM4sbYQrZXDcrKuon2d?p=preview

Comment: It's just that `<kendo-buttongroup>` doesn't support buttons to be passed by any other way than as children. Projection with `<ng-content>` requires children to be accessed differently and also stamping as template doesn't look the same for the consuming component.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I see, thank you. Do you have any advice (direction) how to achieve (not this but) some kind of similar behavior? Or is it absolutely impossible to create a wrapper component?

Comment: It looks like it's not possible with the `<kendo-buttongroup>` except something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular but I guess you'd rather avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need it you can take advantage of using `ngProjectAs` attribute.

In order to have all addition functionality provided by `ButtonGroup`(`k-group-start`, `k-group-end` classes etc) you have to pass buttons array to kendo component.

Here's how it could look like:

```
import { Component, QueryList, ContentChildren, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <kendo-buttongroup>
        <ng-content ngProjectAs="[kendoButton]"></ng-content>
    </kendo-buttongroup>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {

  @ViewChild(ButtonGroup) buttonGroup: ButtonGroup;

  @ContentChildren(Button) buttons: QueryList<Button>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.buttonGroup.buttons = this.buttons;
    this.buttonGroup.ngAfterContentInit();
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/uv1jIysraS1bNEYkfCaR?p=preview)**

See also:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21762
- https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for! My original problem was with Kendo's Grid, but this works with that too. Although I get `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, but only in development mode. Interesting that there are no documentation for `ngProjectAs`.

Comment: The Plunker Example isn't working anymore